# Python OOP self

Tags: python, oop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M845B.png)
I have a question why we can write tong_diem = m1 + m2 + m3, I think like this tong_dem = self.m1 + self.m2 + self.m3 and what is the difference between both ways

I am confused with OOP in python

Comment: copypaste the code instead of taking a screenshot, it's just as easy.

Comment: "why we can write `tong_diem = m1 + m2 + m3`" that should produce a NameError

Answer (score 0):

`m1`, `m2` and `m3` are just variables in `__init__` function, `self.m1`, `self.m2` and `self.m3` are properties of the class. They are not the same thing unless you make them to be. Try this:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = "a"
        self.y = "b"
    
v = SomeClass("x","y")

print(v.x, v.y)
```

You can clearly see that `x` and `y` are completely separate from `self.x` and `self.y` since it prints `a b`, not `x y`. You access properties of an object using `.` when you have an instance of it like `v.x`, but when you don't have an instance yet in the definition, you use `self` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Any Python function or structure must take the `self` argument as a first parameter.
Self is not a keyword; it is only a reference. You may substitute any name or identifier for `self`, such as your name.
Self-meaning is a pointer.

```
class YourClass:
    def __init__(YourName, my_age, my_gender):
        YourName.age = my_age
        YourName.gender = my_gender
    
my_class = YourClass(YouName, 25, 'male')

print(my_class.age, my_class.age)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here m1, m2 and m3 are the variable which exits only in your **init** method but self.m1, self.m2 and self.m3 are class variable reference which are accessible to any other method even if you not pass them as an argument. The reason you are  not able to understand this is because in the given example you are performing operation in same method **init** you can understand its magic when you work on a class with multip methods. For detail explanation about classes in python https://developerdoc.blogspot.com/2023/07/class-in-python.html

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a_ref = a
    def get_val(self):
        return(self.a_ref)
```